# How can I update a div based on a selection?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like, that when user select an option in HTML, I display Block on, an other div.

I put the Function OpenAskuser() in a button, and not work too.
It will be even better, without button. Just when user select the option "yes". The Display=Block

Thank you community!!

```js
function OpenAskuser() {
  var select = document.getElementById("imputYesNo");
  
  if (select.value === "Yes") {
    document.getElementById("AskUser").style.display === "block"
  }
}
```

```html
<p class=title-box-input>Are you member?</p>

<select name="imputYesNo" class=box id="imputYesNo">
  <option value="category-default" selected>Choose</option>
  <option value=Yes>Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<br>

<div class=user-yes id=AskUser style=display:none;>
  <p class=title-box-input>Ok, then what is your nickname?</p>
  <textarea type="text" class=box> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `document.getElementById('imputYesNo').addEventListener('change', OpenAskuser);` after your function.

Comment: "Input", not "imput".

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Don't post "thanks" and don't post comments as answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a `change` listener that calls the function.

Also, `document.getElementById("AskUser").style.display === "block"` is a comparison. Use `=` instead to assign a value to the property:

```js
function OpenAskuser() {
  var select = document.getElementById("imputYesNo");
  if (select.value === "Yes") {
    document.getElementById("AskUser").style.display = "block";
  }

}
```

```html
<p class=title-box-input>Are you member?</p>
<select name="imputYesNo" class=box id="imputYesNo" onchange="OpenAskuser()">
  <option value="category-default" selected>Choose</option>
  <option value=Yes>Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>

</select>

<br>

<div class=user-yes id="AskUser" style=display:none;>
  <p class=title-box-input>Ok, then what is your nickname?</p>
  <textarea type="text" class=box> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lasticot If it solves your question, please consider accepting my answer :)